# Signing Credentials - X509 Certificate with Private Key - SAML2

Tags: c#, x509, saml-2.0, pfx, makecert

I know hardly anything about certificates, with regards that there's a `CA`, `public` and `private key`, and I'm learning as I go. I am creating an SSO login using `SAML 2`, which I have working with the excecption of adding the `<Signature>` element.

**Creating the certificate:**

I have a copy of `makecert.exe` and `pvk2pfx.exe` in a directory. I open `cmd` and type the following:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=Test Cert" -sky exchange -sv testcert.pvk testcert.cer
```

A dialog box pops up, asking for a password and confirm password, which I enter. Another dialog box pops up asking for the password (I'm assuming this is the same one I entered prior, which I have been doing). This creates a `testcert.cer` in the same directory.

I then type this into `cmd`

```
pvk2pfx -pvk testcert.pvk -spc testcert.cer -pfx testcert.pfx
```

**EDIT:** It asks me for a password. I enter the same password (`private key`) that I used when creating the `cer`.

It creates a `pfx` file in the directory.

---

Here's where I am confused. If I import the `cer` file into `MMC`, I can access it:

```
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;

        var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        var storeCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "Test Cert", false);
        if (storeCollection.Count == 1)
        {
            cert = storeCollection[0];
        }

        if (cert == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Certificate", "No certificate found.");
        }

        store.Close();
```

However, when I do this, the private key (property) is `null`. I read that the private key is in the `pfx` file. So, instead of accessing the store, I do this:

`privateKey` is the private key that I used when creating the certificate using `makecert.exe`

```
X509SigningCredentials clientSigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(
     X509Certificate2(@"c:\directory\testcert.pfx", privateKey, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable));
```

I receive an error: `The specified network password is not correct.`

I also attempt to import the `pfx` file into `MMC`, instead of the `cer` file. It asks me for a password. I put the password in that I used to create the certificate using `makecert.exe`. It **ALWAYS** tells me that the password is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to load the pfx not the cer. a certificate ONLY has the public key. A PFX is a package of the cert AND the private key.

Comment: and you should know that makecert.exe is deprecated and is no longer supported.

Comment: @pm100 - OK, but why is the `private key` always incorrect when I attempt to either import into `MMC` and/or load using `X509SigningCredientals`?

Comment: because a pfx has a password, you must supply it when you read it.the docs say that you must supply a password to pvk2pfx but you dont show it in the question

Comment: @pm100 - sorry - left that out. I supplied the same `private key` password as when I made the `cer` file.

Comment: all i can say is that the error says you gave the wrong password. I dont know this tool. Instead use MMC to export to pfx - this I know works - and try to read that with the same code

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `makecert` and `pvk2pfx` was somehow incorrect. I know this isn't an answer, but I found this nifty little tool:

[PluralSight's Self-Cert](http://blog.pluralsight.com/selfcert-create-a-self-signed-certificate-interactively-gui-or-programmatically-in-net)

Basically did the same thing, but when I viewed the certificate it had the:

*You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate*

The other `testcert.cer` did not have this.

Now the code

```
X509SigningCredentials clientSigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(
 X509Certificate2(@"c:\directory\testcert.pfx", privateKey, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable));
```

comes back w/ no issues, and my SAML Assertion is good to go.